# Windows Phone App: Binding to the property of page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, binding

I have made a simple app to study binding process. There is my code:

MainPage.xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    x:Name="thisPage">

    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding Path=TestText}"/>
        <TextBlock
            Text="Saparator"/>
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding ElementName=thisPage, Path=DataContext.TestText}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp1.Resources;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public string TestText;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TestText = "It works!";
        }
    }
}
```

As you see I try two ways to bind Text property of TextBlock controls to the property of MainPage. Whene I am trying to run this app I see no text neither in 1st TextBlock nor in 3rd TextBlock.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try replace field `public string TestText;` to property `public string TestText {get;set;}`

Answer (score 0):

Bindings only work with public properties like `public string TestText { get; set; }`
but only adding that wont help, your `MainPage` will have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface ([how to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and you will have to change your public property a bit to this:

```
private string _textBackingField;

public string TestText
{ 
    get
    {
        return _textBackingField;
    }
    set
    {
        _textBackingField = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are rigth. If I try to set TestText after loading page it doesn't work. Ok, I will try to solve that problem in the way you described.

Comment: I've made followin changes:

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged

and added:

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

and now it works as must! 

Thanks a lot!